# installing python mptt permission denied

Tags: python, ubuntu, django-mptt, ubuntu-12.10

```
~/Django-1.4.2/django-mptt-0.5.5$ python ./setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mptt
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mptt': Permission denied
```

I'm trying to install mptt for django. The problem is that it seems I can't create new files in /usr/local/.../python2.7. the reason is: I'm not the owner.

How do I change that? (it's my computer).
Or,is there a better way for installing it?

Comment: This is not really related to Python (much less to django-mptt); it's the same for _any_ system-wide installation of any software on linux (and many other OS's).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have root access to install a package. Try using the following:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```